# Is plasma at equilibrium considered to be collisionless?

Tags: collision, plasma-physics, equilibrium

I would like to know if Is plasma at equilibrium is considered to be collisionless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plasma can be collisional or non-collisional at equilibrium.  Plasmas which are hot and diffuse, like solar corona, are generally collisionless. Plasmas which are cold and dense, like in a neutron star, are collisional. The standard way to decide the degree of collisionality of a plasma is to take the ratio of the plasma frequency ($\omega_p$) to the collision frequency ($\nu$) as

$\frac{\omega_p}{\nu}=\sqrt{\frac{T^3}{N}},$

where $T$ is the plasma temperature and $N$ is the plasma density.